# Countries in Choropleth maps are not displayed when I add Animation frame parameter

Tags: python, plotly, choropleth

I have been trying to get number of bids for every quarter on a choropleth maps,when i ran the code without animation_frame it was working fine but when i tried to add animation_frame data is not shown on map. It would be very helpful if someone could help me.

code I used without animation frame:

```
import plotly.express as px
px.choropleth(disc_df_quarter,               
              locations="ISO_ALPHA_3", 
              locationmode="ISO-3",
              color="ABOVE_CLIP",
              hover_name="CNTRY_NAME",  
              animation_frame="QUARTER",    
              color_continuous_scale='Plasma',  
              height=600             
)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtZGS.png)
and code with animation frame

```
import plotly.express as px
px.choropleth(disc_df_quarter,               
              locations="ISO_ALPHA_3", 
              locationmode="ISO-3",
              color="ABOVE_CLIP",
              hover_name="CNTRY_NAME",  
              animation_frame="QUARTER",    
              color_continuous_scale='Plasma',  
              height=600  `           
)
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/slmbd.png)

It would be very helpful for me if anyone could help understand atleast what is happening here. Thankyou

It would be very helpful for me if anyone could help understand atleast what is happening here. Thankyou

Comment: I can't find any error elements in the code. Since there is no data presented, I will share the code that corresponds to the animation of the example in the reference, so please try to run this code. `df = px.data.gapminder();fig = px.choropleth(df,locations="iso_alpha", locationmode="ISO-3", color="lifeExp",hover_name="country", animation_frame='year',animation_group='year',color_continuous_scale=px.colors.sequential.Plasma, height=600);fig.show()`

Comment: Thankyou for the reply, Yes i have same syntax for my dataset. But suprisingly it doesnt work for my dataset when i add Animation frame. May be u can let me know if animation frame does any kind of grouping.

Comment: Animation Group is a function that groups together multiple rows of data to be animated. Can you post sample data so we can verify your issue?